# Not able to identify the element in UIAUTOMATORVIEWER

Tags: appium

Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file:

> com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!

Comment: To get better help, please read [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and review your question.

Comment: image is not visible

Answer (score 0):

open your command prompt and type following codes.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Then try to get Device ScreenShot from uiautomatorviewer.
That should work.